# Is it possible to develop a custom plugin of Airflow with user-level access functionality?

Tags: plugins, permissions, airflow

To tell you the conclusion, I want to create a feature where normal users can share DAG permissions with each other.
As far as I know, Airflow's access control is based on RBAC and dependent on FAB.
Is it possible to develop a custom plugin in Airflow to extend user-level access?
I would like to hear opinions on the feasibility of this.